# how to insert the checked value of radio button which is array from another table in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created a test form just to try to send my radio button value which comes from gender table (contain: (1) Male (2) Female ) to another MySQL table named: `ajebaje`. I am having problems with it at the moment. The code below is just a test, I want the radio button to submit the value but it isn't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> ajebaje </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" action= "<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"  method="post"> 
             <table width="20%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                <tr>
                    <td><h4> Student's Gender </h4></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ew6wLoLOro", "result");
                            $sql=mysqli_query($con, "select gender_sl_no, gender_name from gender")                
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                            {
                                 echo '<table>
                                           <input type="radio" name="sexbd" checked="checked"/>'.$row['gender_name'].'           
                                       </table>';
                            }
                        ?>
                   </td>
               </tr>  
               <tr>
                   <td> </td>
                   <td><input type ="submit" name="submit"/> </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </form>
       <?php
           $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ew6wLoLOro", "result");
           $sexbd = $_POST['sexbd'];
           if(isset($_POST['submit']))
           {    
               echo $que="Insert into ajebaje VALUES(default,'$sexbd' )";
               echo " ";
               echo "Your Data Inserted";
               $result = mysqli_query($con,$que);
           }
       ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, it should be sending `sexbd: on` in the form.

For sending value from the form, a value attribute needs to be defined in the input tag. Something like this:

```
echo '<table>
          <input type="radio" name="sexbd" checked="checked" value='.$row['gender_name'].'/>'.$row['gender_name'].'
      </table>';
```

and the rendered form will look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> ajebaje </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" action= "/test"  method="post"> 
             <table width="20%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3">
                <tr>
                    <td><h4> Student's Gender </h4></td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <input type="radio" name="sexbd" checked="checked" value="Male"/> Male          
                        </table>
                        <table>
                            <input type="radio" name="sexbd" checked="checked" value="Female"/> Female          
                       </table>
                   </td>
               </tr>  
               <tr>
                   <td> </td>
                   <td><input type ="submit" name="submit"/> </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now, the submitted value will be `sexbd: Male` or `sexbd: Female`

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Saheb for your helping: It's right code: value='.$row['gender_name'].'/>

Comment: Pleasure @watmas, you can accept the answer, if it is correct :).

Comment: I meant, clicking on the accept check mark under the votes on left of the answer :). read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I don't understand what you want? Please inform abut this in watmas.bd@gmail.com. please help about this.

Comment: I post another problem. Can you solv this. please help for this.